# How To Create endPoint in SNS in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, ios8, amazon-sns

I am able to receive notifications from SNS Console. However, I want to create the endPoints from the app instead of manually in the console. I have looked at iOS7 code, but the classes needed to create the endPoints no longer exist in AWS SDK v2.0.8.

Could anyone who's got it to work post a simple example of creating the endPoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have **SNS Mobile Push and Mobile Analytics Sample** in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples). It demonstrates how to create a platform endpoint.